# Comparing two variables in if statement gives false answers

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm learning Mongoose and making a to-do list. In this program, an if statement is giving false answers all time even though the same condition is working on the above piece of code

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");

const app = express();

let day = date.getDate();

app.post("/delete",function(req,res){
    const checkBoxId = req.body.checkbox;
    const listName = req.body.listName;
   

    // following condition is giving me false statement

    if(listName === day){
        Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkBoxId).then(() => console.log("Data deleted+"));
        res.redirect("/");
    }else{
        console.log(listName);
        List.findOneAndUpdate({name : listName} , {$pull : {items : { _id : checkBoxId}}}).then(() => console.log("Data deleted-"));
        res.redirect("/"+listName);
    }
   
})
```

Comment: You're assigning the date when the process starts. If this process runs for more than one day, you're stuck on that date until you kill it. Better plan: Put that into a function `day()` or assign it within the function in question. You could even import like `const { getDate } = require(...)` and then `if (listName === getDate())` here *assuming* those two are comparable.

Comment: Alternatively to @tadman's suggestion, do this comparison: `if(listName === date.getDate())`. This assumes that both are of the same type, such as `string` or `object`. Also, you can simplify the import to `const date = require('./date.js');`

Answer (score -1):

In the code you provided, the if statement compares listName with day using the strict equality operator (===). If the condition is consistently evaluating to false, there are a few things you can check:

1- Ensure that the values of listName and day are the same. You can add console.log statements to output their values and compare them. For example:

```
console.log("listName:", listName);
console.log("day:", day);
```

Make sure that the values are exactly the same, including whitespace and case sensitivity.

2- Confirm that the data types of listName and day are the same. The strict equality operator (===) compares both value and type. If the data types are different, the condition will evaluate to false. You can check the data types using typeof. For example:

```
console.log("listName type:", typeof listName);
console.log("day type:", typeof day);
```

If the data types are different, you may need to convert one of the variables to match the other.

3- Double-check the logic and flow of your program. Ensure that the listName variable is correctly assigned and populated with the expected value before reaching the if statement. You can add console.log statements to trace the flow and verify that the if statement is executed with the correct values.

By checking these aspects, you should be able to identify the reason why the if statement is consistently evaluating to false.

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT

Comment: i have checked my program it has same value and same data type and both day and listName variable have value before executing if statement and it is running using .localeCompare function but why it is not working with === opertor